# How to create an optional param in nested routes in Nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, nuxt.js

in a nuxt.js app, I have nested routes like this:
`route-1/route-2/route-3`

I want to add an optional param after `route-1` to render the same old route but with extra info(item id or something like that), which mean it will map to 2 route formats

`route-1/:param/route-2/route-3` or `route-1/route-2/route-3`

without duplicate my folder structure

if I add a file with the param name it will be a required param and I will have to duplicate the folder structure without this param to handle the 2 scenarios

Comment: Did you resolve this ?

Comment: in my case, I changed the implementation of my feature to avoid this situation, but the only solution I found in my mind is to extend my routes inside a js file and not depend on the Nuxt.js way to define my routes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case solved with this. I have this pages tree:

```
pages/
--| search/
----| index.vue
--| index.vue
```

I need an optional 'category' param in the search page. I will to extend the routes like this:

```
// nuxt.config.js

export default {
  router: {
    middleware: [...],
    extendRoutes (routes, resolve) {
      routes.push({
        name: 'search-category',
        path: '/search/:category',
        component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/search/index.vue'),
        chunkName: 'pages/search/_category/index'
      })
    }
  }
}
```

If I navigate to `/search` or `/search/my-category` this render the same page in both cases, and in the second case I have the value `my-category` in `$route.params.category` :)

In your case, perhaps something like:

```
// nuxt.config.js

export default {
  router: {
    middleware: [...],
    extendRoutes (routes, resolve) {
      routes.push({
        name: 'my-new-route',
        path: '/route-1/:param/route-2/route-3',
        component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/same-route/index.vue'),
        chunkName: 'pages/same-route/_param/index'
      })
    }
  }
}
```

BTW: `chunkName` is necessary if you use `nuxtI18n` plugin, and after, in this plugin, the configuration for the dynamic route is (in my case):

```
// nuxt.config.js

export default {
  i18n: {
    pages: {
      'search/index': { // <-- route in pages tree
        es: '/buscar',
        en: '/search'
      },
      'search/_category/index': { // <-- dynamic route configured
        es: '/buscar/:category',
        en: '/search/:category'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah, I solved this situation by the same idea but I forgot to write the solution.
Good job @lmfresneda